# Cant scroll to invisible item in nested UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview

I'm new in IOS development and I'm developing an app that uses a tableview. Within the tableviewrow I have a UICollectionView to display items in both directions(horizontal and vertical). The problem comes when I try to scroll to the last item in UICollectionView which is non visible and I want to give this item the focus and set it visible.

** cell = UITableViewCell
** tableCell = UICollectionView

I have tried this but does not work:

cell.tableCell.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at:.bottom, animated: true)

Please somebody help me!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter for the `scrollToItem` function is not of type `IndexPath`.

```
open func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

The type is `UICollectionViewScrollPosition`. So, the code sould be something like:

```
cell.tableCell.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: I know that is not type of IndexPath, I wrote wrong the code above, but that does not work man.

Comment: You didn't provide much code so we can figure out your problem.